# Django href for decrement and increment error for a django cart

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I am working on my first django project. I am creating an ecommerce store and I encountered a problem that I do not know how to solve it.
It is about a personalized cart where I am trying to increment and decrement products within the cart.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
.......
path("cart/<int:id>/", views.increment, name="increment"),
    path("cart/<int:id>/", views.decrement, name="decrement"),
    path("cart/<int:pk>/", views.CartItemDelete.as_view(), name='cart_delete'),
.....]
```

views.py

```
def increment(request, id):
    if request.method == "GET":
        item = UserItem.objects.get(pk=int(id))
        if 0 < (item.quantity + 1) <= item.prod_id.quantity:
            item.quantity += 1
            item.save()
            return redirect('cart')
    return redirect('cart')


def decrement(request, id):
    if request.method == "GET":
        item = UserItem.objects.get(pk=int(id))
        if 0 < (item.quantity - 1) <= item.prod_id.quantity:
            item.quantity -= 1
            item.save()
            return redirect('cart')
    return redirect('cart')

class CartItemDelete(DeleteView):
    model = UserItem
    template_name = "cart_delete.html"
    context_object_name = "crt"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("cart")
```

templates

```
<div class="card" id="cardDisplay">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ prd.img.url }}" alt="Card image" id="image_prod">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">  {{ prd.name }}</h4>
                    <form action="{% url 'cart_qu' %}" method="get">
                    <label>
                    Quantity: <input type="number" name="quantity"  min="1" value="{{ prd.quantity }}" >
                        <input type="hidden" name="{{ prd.pk }}">
                    </label>
                    </form>
                    <a href="{% url "increment" prd.pk %}"><button>+</button></a>

                    <a href="{% url "decrement" prd.pk %}"><button>-</button></a><br>

                    <a href="{% url 'cart_delete' prd.pk %}">Delete</a>
                    <p class="card-text">Price: {{ prd.price }} lei <br>
                </div>
```

My problem is that when I click on "+" button, or "-" button or "Delete", in views.py it is called only increment() function. If I click on "-", it adds extra quantity instead of decreasing, and same for delete... instead of deleting, it increases the quantity of product by 1. In my view, things seems to be ok. I cannot understand where I am mistaken. If anybody can help, I'll be very grateful!
I sincerely appreciate your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django will serve the request with the **first** url that matches the incoming path, all of your paths conflict with one another (match the same incoming path) but "increment" is first so all request will be sent to it.

You need to change your paths so that they do not conflict with one another

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("cart/<int:id>/increment/", views.increment, name="increment"),
    path("cart/<int:id>/decrement/", views.decrement, name="decrement"),
    path("cart/<int:pk>/", views.CartItemDelete.as_view(), name='cart_delete'),
]
```